# Google Cloud - Speech to Text user quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I've just managed how to use the Google Cloud Speech to Text (STT) service with service account credentials file via [Google API Client Library for.NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/).

Our standalone app has STT functionality that should be working only after the user receives the key we personally provide to him. I see that I can generate an API key in the Google Cloud console for service account. I wonder how can I limit the audio seconds quota only for specific key without managing it with our own web service and user authentication.

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stackoverflow.  In your question, you said "... how can I limit the recognition quote ...." ... I'm not understanding that phrase.  Might you be able to clarify or use alternative phrasing?

Comment: @Kolban We can set audio seconds limit per day in console. Is it possible to set the limit for specific key of service account?

Comment: Aha .... I think you are meaning "quota" as opposed to "quote"

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing (that I am aware off) in GCP that will police the amount of speech to text processed on a per authorized caller identity.  I am imagining a story where you have a set of users and each user is processing speech to text.  If any individual user process more than some given amount, you want to "cut them off" from further processing.

If I were faced with that puzzle, I would determine the duration of each fragment of audio processed by each user and store a "total" for each user in an application database.  When each request to process data arrives, I would then query the database to determine if they have reached their limit before allowing the processing to continue.